# Django: Encoding problem on production environment

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding, utf-8

The data is stored in a dataframe as "S\u00c3o Miguel", but the data is returned from template as "S%C3o Miguel", and Python can't find it on the dictionary. How can I solve this?

I developed an application that gets data (as well as the labels) from the database and plots them on charts using the Highcharts library.
When the user clicks on one of the bars of the charts, the label of it is sent back to the server, which returns some values.

The problem is: when the data is first loaded from the database, it is stored in memory in a dataframe, where "S\u00c3o Miguel" is one of the values, but when the user clicks on a chart and the JQuery request is made to the server, it is sent back as "S%C3o Miguel". Due to this, the code can't find this key on the dataframe in the memory.

I've tried to encode the string as UTF-8 with encodeuricomponent on JavaScript prior to sending it back to the server, but no success.
The template already has the  tag.

```
def getFromDatabase():
    [...]
    wfarm_names = pd.read_sql(query, engine) #Gets the data from the database

    return (list(wfarm_names['CL_NAME'].unique())) #Returns a list with all the keys. The value that causes the problem is returned as 'S\u00c3o Miguel'


def getData(request, cluster):
    #In this case, cluster is returned from screen as 'S%C3o Miguel'
    wfarm_names = list(general_frame[general_frame['CL_NAME'] == cluster] 
    #problem occurs here
```

The JQuery request is bellow:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/monitors/turbine-getter/" + cluster + "/",
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
        },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    window.maxmin_vals = data.maxminvals;
    cont.style.display = "inline-block";
    pb.style.display = "none";

    window.pointsDict = {};
    window.current_buffers = data.latlong;

    window.current_cluster = cluster;
    )
    },
                error: function (rs, e) {
                    alert('Sorry, try again.');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery is encoding the url, you can decode like this:

```
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> decoded = parse.unquote(url)
```